# CSRF token error while working with REST Api in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, csrf

I'm working in codeigniter v3 and i got error when i use CSRF token while working with REST API
in postman error looks like this..

[image]

Can anybody help me with this. Also i want to disable CSRF protection for several urls. I tried to achieve this by placing the url in

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('webservice');
```

but it still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the full uri like this:

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
    'webservice/addCandidate'
);
```

Or with regex :

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
    'webservice/[a-zA-Z]+'
);
```

Comment: Thank you mate, how can i disable this in such urls like 
http://coderevision.com/candidate/addCertificates/1 means that contains numbers as a parameter. please give me a solution for that also.

Comment: @poojanmehtaPM You're welcome, regex for number : [0-9]+ Example : webservice/[a-zA-Z]+/[0-9]+

Comment: Thank you @Maxime D, can you please tell me how can i know that, disable is working or not because i can still see csrf hidden field code in browser html.

Comment: @poojanmehtaPM delete your cookie

Comment: i deleted the cookie but i can still see the csrf field in browser. :(